# R Studio - Map binary columns of df to row details of another and match?

Tags: r, match, dplyr

I have these two datasets below - "data", which is a list of people competing in tournaments with binary columns indicating which ones they're playing in, and "tourn_details", which indicates what dates these tournaments take place in.

```
name <- c('Sarah', 'Josh', 'Ben')
tourn1 <- c(1, 1, 0)
tourn2 <- c(0, 1, 1)
tourn3 <- c(1, 0, 0)
data <- data.frame(name, tourn1, tourn2, tourn3)

tourns <- c("tourn1", "tourn2", "tourn3")
dates <- c("2020-01-01, 2020-01-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02, 2020-01-03")
tourn_details <- data.frame(tourns, dates)
```

I'm now trying to add a column to "data" called "playing dates" that will be a list of all the days that the competitor is playing in. For example, Sarah is playing in tourn1 and tourn3 - using the tourn_details, this means she's playing Jan 1, Jan 2 (for tourn 1), and Jan 2, Jan 3 (for tourn 3). Her "playing dates" should say '2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03" (note the repeated dates).

Last part is I want to add a column that shows how many games each player is playing in from a certain date. Let's say I set the date to Jan 1 - I want to know how many games are upcoming for each player. For Sarah, on Jan 1, this should be equal to 3 (as she's playing two games on Jan 2, and one on Jan 3).

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can provide more details!

Comment: What constitutes "upcoming"? For example, what if there was a tournament on Jan. 4 in `tour_details`? At what point is a tournament not included in your player count?

Comment: For simplicity, I meant all upcoming, but I'm actually looking for something like "games in next 7 days" (or n days). So yes, to your point, would like it to be upcoming in the next 7 days, for example.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much - works great! Accepted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(starts_with("tourn"), ~ ifelse(.x, cur_column(), NA))) %>% 
  tidyr::unite(tourn, starts_with("tourn"), sep = ", ", na.rm = T) %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(playing_dates = tourn_details[str_detect(tourn, tourn_details$tourns), "dates"] %>%
                  paste(collapse = ", "),
                upcoming = sum(as.Date(str_split(playing_dates, ", ")[[1]]) %in%
                                 seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), length.out = 7, by = 1))) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
  name  tourn          playing_dates                                  upcoming
  <chr> <chr>          <chr>                                             <int>
1 Sarah tourn1, tourn3 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03        4
2 Josh  tourn1, tourn2 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-01                    3
3 Ben   tourn2         2020-01-01                                            1
```

---

You can adjust `as.Date("2020-01-01")` to be whatever start date you'd like. It will look seven days out. This works by creating a sequence (`seq`) of dates from your start date one day at a time (`by = 1`) until the sequence is seven elements long (`length.out = 7`).